# MySQL's atomic and thread safe nature

Tags: mysql, multi-thread

I understood that MySQL is thread-safe, which means that even though two threads trying to access the DB, it will be safe since there is a lock mechanism.

But I like to ask one question, which you might find as basic.
Let's say we have some really bad SQL queries. It will take 15 seconds to run and finish.

If some thread runs this query, does it means that other request should wait for 15 seconds no matter what?
Is this is the main reason we always optimise our SQL query?

Answer (score 2):

It depends.

The Engine InnoDB locks rows, not whole table or databases.  That way, two queries can be modifying different rows without essentially no interference.

Also, `SELECTs` do not block `SELECTs`.  It is only writes that *may* cause locks.  Technically speaking even `SELECTs` take out "shared read locks", but that is mostly to alert a *write* that the Select is busy with the row(s).

InnoDB is very good at quickly discovering "deadlocks".  This is where one connection is locking A and trying to lock B, and another connection has B and wants A.  One of the "transactions" will be aborted; the other will run to completion.

There is another situation (like what you mentioned) where the engine can deduce that one connection is blocking another, but the lock can be resolved by letting one connection finish, while stalling the other.  (Cf: `lock_wait_timeout`.)

Both types of blockages occur less frequently if you can speed up the queries.  Of course, another reason for optimizing is that no one wants to wait 15 seconds for a web page to load.

The general topic is "ACID".